# Pandas - Lambda inside apply to return a row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, lambda, apply

I was expecting to get whole rows when using lambda function inside a apply in Pandas DataFrame, but it looks I'm getting a "single element".

Look that code:

```
# Data sample
reviews_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'price': {0: None, 1: 15.0, 2: 14.0, 3: 13.0}, 
    'country': {0: 'Italy', 1: 'Portugal', 2: 'US', 3: 'US'}, 
    'points': {0: 87, 1: 87, 2: 87, 3: 87}
})

print(reviews_2)

mean_price_2 = reviews_2.price.mean() # a value to centering

def remean_points(row):
    row.price = row.price - mean_price_2
    return row

centered_price_2 = reviews_2.apply(remean_points, axis='columns') # returns a DataFrame

print(centered_price_2)
```

That "apply" returns a DataFrame. That is my expected output!

So, I tried to use a lambda function, doing:

```
reviews_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'price': {0: None, 1: 15.0, 2: 14.0, 3: 13.0}, 
    'country': {0: 'Italy', 1: 'Portugal', 2: 'US', 3: 'US'}, 
    'points': {0: 87, 1: 87, 2: 87, 3: 87}
})
print(reviews_2)

mean_price_2 = reviews_2.price.mean()

centered_price_2 = reviews_2.apply(lambda p: p.price - mean_price_2, axis='columns') # returns a Serie!

print(centered_price_2)
```

But now, "apply" returns a Serie!

I know the `apply` tries to identify the type.
I was waiting to get a row, but it looks to return a "single element"...

So my question:

> `p` in the lambda function should not be a row?

Interesting:

> If I do `centered_price_2 = reviews_2.apply(lambda p: p, axis='columns')`,
> I get a DataFrame...

Yet:

> How to use `lambda` and `apply` functions and to be sure about output type?!

Comment: What's the required/desired output that you're looking for? That `centered_price_2` - what do you need it to be? A new column?

Comment: `p` in the lambda function *is* a row. The problem is the difference in return types. The first function returns a `pd.Series` object, the second function returns a scalar. The fact that it is a lambda function is irrelevant (it's pretty much never relevant)

Comment: So, it is the equivalent of `def remean_points(row): return row.price - mean_price_2`

Comment: @DanailPetrov I wan to get a DataFrame, different from Kaggle exercise...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In this case, I would like to get a DataFrame, not only the Serie.
Actually, I want to better use lambda functions! ;)

Comment: @marcio ok... so then *return a non-scalar value*. Honestly, lamba functions are just sugar. Why don't you just use your other function? Why *must* you use a lambda function? There is no reason.

Comment: In any case, you almost certainly shouldn't be using `.apply` for this to begin with.

Comment: I'm studying, learning! So that looked very interesting to me! But Thank you for the advise!
And yes, to get a Serie, ```def remean_points(row): return row.price - mean_price_2 ``` would be a very better solution!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226574/discussion-between-marcio-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was done in **2020**, and now, in **2024**, reviewing my open questions I understand Pandas a bit more (just a bit)!

So...

My *mistake* was here:

```
mean_price_2 = reviews_2.price.mean()

centered_price_2 = reviews_2.apply(lambda p: p.price - mean_price_2, axis='columns') # returns a Serie!
```

I explain:

1. Like I said in that time, `apply` tries to identify the used type.
2. `mean_price_2 = reviews_2.price.mean()` is a `Serie`.
3. So, even `p` been a whole `DataFrame`, my lambda function expression `centered_price_2 = reviews_2.apply(lambda p: p.price - mean_price_2, axis='columns')` also returns a `Serie`!
4. Because, `p.price - mean_price_2` returns a `Serie`.

In 2020, I **wrongly** did think `lambda p:...` <strike>should always return</strike> a `DataFrame` since `p` **is** a `DataFrame`.
The `lambda` returned type commes from the evaluated expression...

One solution to *fix* my code would be:

```
reviews_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'price': {0: None, 1: 15.0, 2: 14.0, 3: 13.0}, 
    'country': {0: 'Italy', 1: 'Portugal', 2: 'US', 3: 'US'}, 
    'points': {0: 87, 1: 87, 2: 87, 3: 87}
})

print(reviews_2)

mean_price_2 = reviews_2.price.mean()

# note the next two lines
centered_price_2 = reviews_2 # 'Copy' the DataFrame
centered_price_2.price = reviews_2.apply(lambda p: p.price - mean_price_2, axis='columns') # Only change the desired column!

print(centered_price_2)
```

Happy 2024!

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what is the exact output expected so I hope this is what you're looking for?

The `newcol` will have the `price` - `mean price`.

```
>>> reviews_2['newcol'] = reviews_2['price'].apply(lambda x: x - reviews_2.price.mean())

   price   country  points  newcol
0    NaN     Italy      87     NaN
1   15.0  Portugal      87     1.0
2   14.0        US      87     0.0
3   13.0        US      87    -1.0
```

Comment: I edited my post to say the expected output: a new DataFrame like the first one!

Comment: This really should be `reviews_2['price'] = reviews_2['price'] - reviews_2['price'].mean()`